# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't shutdown ,reboot on laptop

Tags: dual-boot

I have just installed Ubuntu as second system after Windows 10.
For the first time Ubuntu stop responding after few minutes after logging in .
Now everything is ok except I can't shut down and reboot it.
When i click on reboot or shutdown mouse disappeared and nothing happened  .I need hold my power button to turn off it.
Ubuntu and windows is on ssd .
Laptop just new and on Windows everything is ok

PS I cant open settings in Ubuntu it freezes

Comment: It works.It very fast to boot now. What this parameter do?(no mode set).But i see that in walpaper there are lines(only there!!) See photo b.radikal.ru/b35/1906/dd/16150939ddce.jpg

Comment: https://c.radikal.ru/c24/1906/fa/d2019cd916f2.jpg

Comment: I forget reboot. So when update i didnt do anything?

Comment: I mean i must forget about this when upgrading system? PS why on that walpaper was lines and why linux 19.04 live freezes?

Comment: actually it depends. for some hardware under 19.04 that fix is not necessary, for some other hardware it is still necessary, you'll have to try and find out.

Comment: I have problem.Earlier i can change brightness just by pressing fn+f8 but now cant

Comment: make that into another issue, that's entirely unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your laptop has newer hardware but there is a solution for this.

Open a terminal, type:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

then on this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

add `nomodeset`, like this :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then type <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you'll be back in the terminal with the file saved, now you can type :

```
sudo update-grub
```

this will solve the issue.